# Activating my unlocked iPhone 4S using a Friend's SIM temporarily

Tags: iphone, sim

So I bought an unlocked iPhone 4S and im stuck at activation. I just want to get into the phone, get some apps and other stuff via Wifi. 
My friend has an unlocked iphone as well, can I put his SIM into my iPhone to get through activation and then remove it ?

Will that affect my phone or soon to have SIM ? Will that affect his SIM or his iPhone ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes. No it won't affect your phone.

Comment: are you sure ? Have you tried it yourself or seen it happen ? If so, please post this as a reply so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. An iPhone requires a SIM to activate. If the phone was locked to a specific carrier, it would require a SIM from that respective service provider. Since your iPhone is factory unlocked, any SIM (provided it's a micro-SIM) will suffice for activation. SIM cards to do not affect your device. You could get SIM cards from Fido, Rogers, Bell, AT&T, and Verizon and use each one every hour if you wish. SIMs only allow your device to connect to the carriers towers, that is all. That's what SIMs are for, to talk to the carrier and say, "Hey, I'm authorized to be here."

Comment: please post this as answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. No it won't affect your phone.

An iPhone requires a SIM to activate. If the phone was locked to a specific carrier, it would require a SIM from that respective service provider. Since your iPhone is factory unlocked, any SIM (provided it's a micro-SIM) will suffice for activation. SIM cards to do not affect your device. You could get SIM cards from Fido, Rogers, Bell, AT&T, and Verizon and use each one every hour if you wish. This is why "world phones" (devices that are not locked to a specific carrier) are appealing to those that travel. They can use one SIM card in North America, for example, and another one in Asia during their travels.

SIMs only allow your device to connect to the carrier's towers, that is all. That's what SIMs are for, to talk to the carrier and say, "Hey, I'm authorized to be here." Older technology (CDMA) required direct device activation. This meant having to call the carrier and get the device activated. Should you change your device, you would have to call again to activate the new one. SIM cards (for the newer GSM network) solved this problem by registering the SIM and not the device. Once a SIM is registered, any device its plugged into has access to that network.